# Refactor Jquery find specific elements using find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day to all,

This isn't really a problem. But I just want to know if there is another way of finding the values for specific elements. So I have here a sample.

```
<table class="test">
  <thead>..</thead>
  <tfoot>..</tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="foo>1<td>
      <td class="foo>7<td>
      <td class="foo>1<td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="test">
  <thead>..</thead>
  <tfoot>..</tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="foo>1<td>
      <td class="foo>3<td>
      <td class="foo>2<td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="test">
  <thead>..</thead>
  <tfoot>..</tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="foo>5<td>
      <td class="foo>1<td>
      <td class="foo>3<td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My solution:

```
$("table.test").each(function() {
  alert($(this).find("td.foo:first").text());
});
```

So this will alert all the first `<td class="foo">` of each table.

I wonder if there's another way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("table.test").find("td.foo:first").each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/87Zdu/)

Comment: Ohh so you can chain things like this. Thanks. It really helped. One question though, if you chain things like that will `$(this)` refer to the last selector?

Comment: @BoyPasmo `this` inside `each` will refer to the dom element which is being iterated through in this case the `td.foo:first` elements